# Library for hierarchical graph visualisation with Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, graph, visualization

I'm looking for a library to use with Angular 11 to show and interact with hierarchical graphs. I would like to zoom in and out the graph, click nodes and add events on click, hover etc. The problem is that my graphs are very big (thousands of nodes and edges - they are deep learning models).

I tried [ngx-graph](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/) and it works great until the graph has more than 500 nodes. When it's getting bigger, the performance is very low.

I also tried [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/index.html#chart-type-graph) and it has no performance issues, but it doesn't support hierarchical graph layout.

Do you have any recommendations? I would prefer MIT or Apache license.

Comment: https://js.cytoscape.org/#performance/background has some optimazation possiblities but I don't know if that's enough for your needs.